# Calendar View Meal Planner

Tags: java, android, calendar, calendarview

I'm trying to create a cooking application

can anyone help me in trying to create a calendar view where you click on a day and a new dialog box appears with breakfast lunch and dinner and you then click either breakfast dinner or lunch and you're brought to a new page where you type in a food (i have an sqlite database set up with foods)

I have a calendar view set up

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Calendar_View"
android:id="@+id/calendar_view">

<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

calendar_view.java

```
public class Calendar_View extends Activity {

CalendarView cal;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calendar_view);

    cal = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);

    cal.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                                        int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Selected Date is\n\n"
                            + dayOfMonth + " : " + month + " : " + year,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.calendar_view, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

but when i click on my the link to it on the homepage it won't come up

```
public class Home_Screen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    //click on search by recipe
    if (v.getId() == R.id.search_recipes) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
    }

    //click on search by ingredients
    if (v.getId() == R.id.search_by_ingredients) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Search_By_Ingredients.class));
    }

    //click on meal planner
    if (v.getId() == R.id.calendar_view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Calendar_View.class));
    }

    //click on food allergies
    if (v.getId() == R.id.food_allergies) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Food_Allergies.class));
    }

}

}
```

does anyone have any ideas on how to fix that and how to make a meal planner like i have suggested above